# Splitting number and words pandas preserving the index

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, numbers

I have the column of my dataframe df like col1. From col1, I need to create two columns of number and words. df['col1'] split into df['code'], df['name'].

```
(index)                                  col1

94                                      520XX
111                                     316aa
114                                     Entry
144                                 325 Sport
146                                 xColor35d
166                               420 M Sport
167                                        XX
199                                        XX
225                                    645 Ai
```

I tried in this way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

result = df['col1'].str.split('(\d+)([A-Za- z]+)', expand=True)
result = result.loc[:,[0,1,2,3]]
result.rename(columns={0:'split_0',1:'split_1', 2:'split_2',3:'split_3'}, inplace=True)
result['split_0'] = result['split_0'].fillna(value=pd.np.NaN, inplace=False)
result['split_0'] = result['split_0'].astype(str).replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
result
```

Result is

```
    split_0       split_1   split_2  split_3  

94  520            XX       None    None    
111 NaN            316      aa  
114 Entry          None     None    None
144 325 Sport      None     None    None
146 xColor         35       d   
166 420 M Sport    None     None    None
167 XX             None     None    None
199 XX             None     None    None
225 645 Ci         None     None
```

My problem rises when I try to split the column 'split_0' column into number and words and subsequently concatenate and have at the end only two columns containing numbers and words from all 'split_*' columns, preserving the index like:

```
    code           name

94  520            XX           
111 316            aa           
114 NaN            Entry    
144 325            Sport    
146 35             xColor d 
166 420            M Sport  
167 NaN            XX       
199 NaN            XX       
225 645            Ci
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `str.extractall` and `pd.concat`

```
code = (df.col1.str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]+ ' ') \
                   .sum(level=0).str.strip().rename('code')
name = (df.col1.str.extractall('([a-zA-Z]+)')[0]+ ' ') \
                   .sum(level=0).str.strip().rename('name')

df_out = pd.concat([code, name], axis=1)


Out[139]:
    code      name
94   520        XX
111  316        aa
114  NaN     Entry
144  325     Sport
146   35  xColor d
166  420   M Sport
167  NaN        XX
199  NaN        XX
225  645        Ai
```

Comment: I have it! Great, thanks! Please, could you be able to explain me what was wrong in what I did?

Comment: @Annalix:  `\d+[A-Za- z]+` means digits following characters. Your strings get splitted when they encouters `digits following characters`. On  `520XX`, it splits to `[ , ]` (list of 2 empty strings) because the split gets char before and after `520XX`. There is none so it is list of 2 empty strings. You use above pattern but adding capturing option `(\d+)([A-Za- z]+)`. It means besides  splitting it also captures digits and chars, so it returns `[, 520, XX, ]` (4 items). It expands to 4 columns where 1st and last column are empty. Just apply the same logic to other rows to see the rest

Comment: Ok, I see all that None because the space item. Thanks!